# Delete user changes after the end of a session

Tags: configuration, user-profile

In my university's labs (running ubuntu 14.04) I have noticed that some people like to make quite a lot of changes - visual and config.

I personally think that everyone should be able to work with a configuration which they like and feel comfortable with, so I started wondering if there is a way when there are certain settings set for a user, when you log in, you can edit everything you wish and once you log out, all the changes are reverted?

I think such a thing will fit the university's needs quite awesomely and I am not sure if they haven't done it out of lazyness or because it is impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each user has a unique account, this is how things would function. It is the normal mode of operation for a multi-user Linux system.

If it is a shared account, (i.e. everyone logs in as something like "GenericUser") it is a bit more difficult. There are many ways it *could* be implemented, but most of them make more work to do and more things that can break. This adds work for the University technical support staff to keep up with, something they probably have too much of already.

The best way might be to have the /home/$user filesystem of that shared/default user load as a ramfs/tmpfs. Students can make all the changes they want, but when the account is logged out all changes are lost. Next time the account logs in, the filesystem is loaded from the disk into the ramfs/tmpfs again with none of the changes.

Comment: That sounds cool, can you detail the setup of this ramfs/tempfs user?